# push command instead of cp command when dealing with system root

Tags: android, adb

I'm using adb to move files in my android device from storage to system
is there any way that I can use push command instead of cp when I want to transfer a folder that contain files and folders inside it from storage to system coz push command allows me to transfer the folders inside my main folder but the cp command transfer just the files or is there any other way??

this is a an example :

```
adb shell "su -c ' stop'"
adb shell "su -c ' mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system'"
adb shell "su -c ' cp /data/local/tmp/system/app/* /system/app'"
adb shell "su -c ' cp /data/local/tmp/system/framework/* /system/framework'"
adb shell "su -c ' cp /data/local/tmp/system/prive-app/* /system/priv-app'"
adb shell "su -c ' cp /data/local/tmp/system/fontes/* /system/fonts'"
adb shell "su -c ' cp /data/local/tmp/system/csc/* /system/csc'"
adb shell "su -c ' cp /data/local/tmp/system/Samsung_962_r1-2_ARlsUN_xt9_ALM3.ldb /system/T9DB'"
adb shell "su -c ' start'"
```

cant I short this code to just one line like

```
adb shell "su -c ' cp /data/local/tmp/system/* /system'"
```

it gives me error message when I use this one!

Comment: If you want to copy folders as well, you must change to "cp" to "cp -r"

Comment: Use some periods and commas in your question. It's hard to read.